# java bufferedReader.readLine() can't read whole file line

Tags: java, bufferedreader, nio

our back-end program read txt file and process something line by line.

for reading file line by line, It is using `bufferedReader.readLine`.

but sometimes, once a quarter, `bufferedReader` can't read whole line.

if there is **1000** line file actually, `readLine()` just read 1~530.

I'm sure file is well formed. when I try reading file again after this error, It can read whole line perfectly.

this file is uploaded via **FTP** and file watcher batch to detect file is running.

below is code:

```
String fromFilePath = "/DATA/EXAMPLE.TXT"; //upload filepath example
String toFilePath = "/DATA/PROC/EXAMPLE.TXT";  //filepath to move

//read file after moving to another directory, to avoid catching file by file watcher and file in target path never exist. 
Files.move(Paths.get(fromFilePath), Paths.get(toFilePath), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(toFilePath, "UTF-8")));
int fileRowCount = 0;
String readLineResult = null;

while(readLineResult = br.readLine() != null){
  fileRowCount++;

  doBusinessLogic(readLineResult);

}

log.info("file log count {}", fileRowCount);

//confirm process to solve this problem. 
br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(toFilePath, "UTF-8")));
int assertCount= 0;

while(br.readLine() != null){
  assertCount++;
}

//it always print 'true' when occuring error, although BufferedReader is initialized newly 
log.info("assert {}", assertCount==fileRowCount);
```

`fileRowCount` can't print whole line number. of course, `doBusinessLogic` is also executed partially.

**OS : redhat 7.4**

**java version :  1.7.0_181**

Comment: Welcome, in this code block you aren't closing the resource. In Java 7 you can use try with resources to handle close finally patterns: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `while ((readLineResult = br.readLine()) != null){` you will want braces around the readline to help it evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely reason for that behaviour is that your program starts reading while the file upload is still in progress. To avoid that, you should make sure your program only reads completely transfered files. If you have any influence on the upload procress, let the uploader use a temporary file name (that is ignored by the reader), then rename the file after the transfer. If that is not possible, you could either check the file for completeness before reading (if the file end is clearly recognizeable) or wait for some time after the file appears before you start reading. That last option is probably the easiest to implement, but setting the delay long enough to ensure safe completion of the transfer takes some guesswork.

Answer (score -1):

use `(readLineResult = br.readLine()) != null` in your while loop
Also it is good to use try catch block when reading a file. For reference you can visit [here](https://www.guru99.com/buffered-reader-in-java.html).

Comment: I guess my answer is same as @James I hope it helps.